# Python - Dumping a dictionary to certain format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary that I am currently writing out to a file, and the output looks like this:

```
{
    "1"|"GRP",
    "10"|"GRP",
    "100"|"GRP",
     ....
}
```

I want it to look more like this:

```
    1|GRP
    10|GRP
    100|GRP
     ....
```

Here is the code I am using to produce these results:

```
with open('some_namespace.belns', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(hgnc_ns_dict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', '|'))
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but what you are writing out is not anywhere close to JSON. Can you be more specific as to why you think you are generating JSON?

Comment: it is formatted json no?

Comment: You won't be writing JSON. JSON is javascript object notation, there are no objects left in your example.

Comment: @Houdini: I know you think that, but it is not. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I dont care what format I write it out in. I just want it to look the way it does in my second example in the end.

Comment: Can you take a step back and tell us the larger picture? What are you communicating with that needs that format?

Comment: Please explain for the downvote, whoever it was. Second, I am producing a namespace file that looks like `gene_symbol|encoding`. the data on the LHS and RHS of the pipe is currently stored in a dictionary in key-value pairs.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but as others have commented, what you are requesting isn't JSON. At best it is `csv` with `delim='|'`

Comment: @msw thank you I edited my question. Being incorrect about what you are asking for shouldn't be a downvote. Actually, directly from stackoverflow: `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect`. I do not feel my question falls into any of these categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get this exact format using json, but you can do something like the following to get the expected result:

```
with open('some_namespace.belns', 'w') as fp:
    for key in sorted(hgnc_ns_dict):
        fp.write('    {0}|{1}\n'.format(key, hgnc_ns_dict[key]))
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you. I think b/c I was using the `json` module, it was showing double "s around the string values. So, I think this can also be done with just simple string concatenation provided I just use `write` instead of the `json` module.